# Creating Nested XML Document using Linq to Entities and XSD

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd, entities

I'm trying to create and XML document from a SQL datasource using Linq to Entities.  I used XSD to create the classes for the XML document.  The XML structure is as follows (partial listing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExecutedShipment>
   <ExecutedShipmentIdentifier>098098</ExecutedShipmentIdentifier>
   <ShipDirection>Outbound</ShipDirection>
   <FreightTerms>Pre-Paid</FreightTerms>
   <CarrierSCAC>SEFL</CarrierSCAC>
   <EquipmentType>LTL</EquipmentType>
   <CarrierTrackingNumber>100283534</CarrierTrackingNumber>
   <LoadList>
      <Load>
         <ExecutedLoadIdentifier>098098</ExecutedLoadIdentifier>
         <Schedule>
            <ActualShipDate timezone="EST">2004-03-19T15:35:00</ActualShipDate>
         </Schedule>
         <PickupSequenceNumber>1</PickupSequenceNumber>
         <DropoffSequenceNumber>1</DropoffSequenceNumber>
         <ShipFrom>
            <SiteIdentifier>123456</SiteIdentifier>
         <FullName>ABC Inc.</FullName>
             <Location>
               <Address1>354 Main Street</Address1>
               <Postal>01234</Postal>
               <Country>US</Country>
            </Location>
        </ShipFrom>
```

Here's the code I'm using to populate the class so that I can serialize it to an XML file:

```
    List<ExecutedShipment> Shipments = new List<ExecutedShipment>();

    Shipments = (
                from sh in ShipData.shiphead
                where sh.shipdate >= Yesterday && sh.shipdate <= Yesterday
                select new ExecutedShipment
                {
                    ExecutedShipmentIdentifier = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sh.packnum),
                    ShipDirection = "Outbound",
                    FreightTerms = "Pre-Paid",
                    CarrierSCAC = sh.shipviacode,
                    EquipmentType = "LTL",
                    CarrierTrackingNumber = sh.trackingnumber,
                    LoadList = new ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoad
                               { 
                                   ExecutedLoadIdentifier = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sh.packnum),
                                   DropoffSequenceNumber = "TEST"
                                   //Schedule = (new ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoadScheduleActualShipDate
                                   //           {
                                   //               timezone = "EST",
                                   //               Value = "0000-00-00"  //sh.shipdate
                                   //           }).ToArray()
                               }

                }).ToList<ExecutedShipment>();
```

The first part of the code works fine.  It's when I get to 'LoadList' that I have a problem.  In Visual Studio the 'new ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoad' is underlined in red and the error is Cannot implicitly convert type 'ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoad' to 'ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoad[]'.  'LoadList' is an array, but nothing I've tried to convert to an array of the same type has worked.  So, generally speaking, how do you reference and assign values to sub-elements within the XSD generated class?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to create an array and put the instances in the array declaration, like so:

```
// Start array declaration.
LoadList = new [] {

    // First element.
    new ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoad { 
        ExecutedLoadIdentifier = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)sh.packnum),
        DropoffSequenceNumber = "TEST"
        //Schedule = (new ExecutedShipmentLoadListLoadScheduleActualShipDate
        //           {
        //               timezone = "EST",
        //               Value = "0000-00-00"  //sh.shipdate
        //           }).ToArray()
    }

    // Other elements here.

// End array declaration
}
```